# google map source to destinstion is not_found my project in server its working in local

Tags: javascript, php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directions service</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <!-- <div id="floating-panel">-->
    <b>Start: </b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    <b>End: </b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
          origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
          destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBhhTP6lk0JJhcYJcNb_Q8CWsFunP_8UIM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code error coming in not found directions in server but in localhost is working please find me out in local its static data source and destination 
but in server dynamic data please find me out

Comment: Please add error message.

Comment: My error is Directions request failed due to ' NOT_FOUND